# Join With List Collection

Tags: linq, join

I try to write a join LINQ query. but it's raise syntax error. what can i do? i need user's conversation messages.

```
/*
Conversations = Header info
c.Users = List<ApplicationUser>
*/
public List<ConversationMessage> GetAll(ApplicationUser user)
{
    var query = from m in _db.ConversationMessages
        join c in _db.Conversations on m.ConversationId equals c.ConversationId
        join u in _db.Users on c.Users.Contains(user) 
        select m;
}
```

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you will tell us _what the specific syntax error is_.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it should be something more like this:

```
public List<ConversationMessage> GetAll(ApplicationUser user)
{
    var query =
        from c in _db.Conversations
        where c.Users.Contains(user)
        join m in _db.ConversationMessages on c.ConversationId equals m.ConversationId
        select m;

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: it's raise this error. Unable to create a constant value of type 'Entities.ApplicationUser'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: @Yargicx - Yes, that's probably true. You need to do a bit of debugging to get the code to work for your circumstances. I don't know your object model so I did as much as I could without knowing it. You probably need to change `user` to something like `user.Id`, but I suspect that the `c.Users.Contains` part needs to change too to work with ids. But, as I said, it's up to you to debug.

Comment: var query = from c in _db.Conversations
where c.Users.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(user.Id)
join m in _db.ConversationMessages on c.ConversationId equals m.ConversationId
select m;

Comment: how can write this code with join? i think joins performance much better.

Comment: @Yargicx - Joins often perform slower, so don't worry about performance until you know you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from c in _db.Conversations
            where c.Users.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(user.Id)
            join m in _db.ConversationMessages on c.ConversationId equals m.ConversationId
           select m;
```